# I want to transfer data form one php file to another to update rows using that data

Tags: php, html

I have a MYSQL table with Update link  button on each row. he Update link goes to update.php which has a form. now the problem is i want to fetch the id from the row clicked on to update.php and show that id on update form in id field. i have transfered the id variable through link. but in other .php file it is printing anything.
i want to print id in update form field when i click on update button
Here is the code in index.php file
Display.php=>

```
<html>
<head><title>Support Page</title></head>
<body>
    <table border="2">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>NAME</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>phone no</th>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Company</th>
     <th>Query</th>
     <th>Any Other Info</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Operations</th>
    </tr>
     

    
<?php
$query ="SELECT * FROM query_data";
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($data);

echo $result['id']."  ".$result['Name']."  ".$result['Email']."  ".$result['phone_no']."  ".$result['Product_Name']."  ".$result['Company']."  ".$result['Query']."  ".$result['Any_Other_Query']."  ".$result['Status']."  ".$result['Date'];

if($total!=0)
{
    while($result =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
    {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$result['id']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Name']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Email']."</td>
            <td>".$result['phone_no']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Product_Name']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Company']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Query']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Any_Other_Info']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Status']."</td>
            <td>".$result['Date']."</td>
            <td><a href = 'http://mexyz.tech/?page_id=586?i=$result[id]'>Update</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}else{
    echo "No record found";
}
?>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is update.php=>

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$id = $_GET['i'];
?> 
    form action="" method="GET">
        Enter id :      <input type="text" value="<?php echo "id" ?>" name="id" required>
        <br><br>
        Enter Query Code:    <input type="text" name="QC">
        <br><br>
        <td> 
            <select name="Status">
                <option>Choose Option</option>
                <option>Pending</option>
                <option>Assigned</option>
                <option>Resolved</option>
            </select> 
        </td>
        <br><br>          
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $ids = $_POST['id'];
        $s = $_POST['Status'];
        $QC = $_POST['QC'];
        
        $tablename = "query_data";
        $data = array("Status" =>$s, "Query_Code" =>$QC);
        $wherecondition = array('id' => $ids);
        
        $updated = $wpdb->update( $tablename, $data, $wherecondition ); 
       // $sql = $wpdb->insert("query_data",array("Status" =>$s,"Query_Code" =>$QC));
        
        if ($updated == true) {
            echo "<script> alert('Submitted Successfully!...')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
if (astra_page_layout() == 'right-sidebar') :
    get_sidebar();
endif;

get_footer();
```

Comment: WHy are you echoing occurances from the `$result` array before you actually populate that array with the fetch

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you are trying to achieve from your code but
you should pass your update link with a query string if you want to get the id in your update.

this is how to pass the link with a query string

```
<td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">Update</a></td>
```

if you do it that way then got to your update page

and do this

```
 if (isset($_GET[id])){

 $id = $_GET[id];

 }
```